# Android Patterns.WEB_URL not working correctly

Tags: java, android

I am separating the texts in SocialTextView according to the links. But here, `"aaa.bbb"` as a link is also perceived as text.

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text) // --> "aaa.bbb" as link
```

I used a structure that customized it. But this is also the result.

[image]

```
private static Pattern getLinkPattern() {
    if (patternLink == null) {
        patternLink = Pattern.compile(new StringBuilder()
                .append("((?:(http|https|Http|Https|rtsp|Rtsp):")
                .append("\\/\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)")
                .append("\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?:\\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_")
                .append("\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\\@)?)?")
                .append("((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}\\.)+")   // named host
                .append("(?:")   // plus top level domain
                .append("(?:aero|arpa|asia|a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz])")
                .append("|(?:biz|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz])")
                .append("|(?:cat|com|coop|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz])")
                .append("|d[ejkmoz]")
                .append("|(?:edu|e[cegrstu])")
                .append("|f[ijkmor]")
                .append("|(?:gov|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy])")
                .append("|h[kmnrtu]")
                .append("|(?:info|int|i[delmnoqrst])")
                .append("|(?:jobs|j[emop])")
                .append("|k[eghimnrwyz]")
                .append("|l[abcikrstuvy]")
                .append("|(?:mil|mobi|museum|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz])")
                .append("|(?:name|net|n[acefgilopruz])")
                .append("|(?:org|om)")
                .append("|(?:pro|p[aefghklmnrstwy])")
                .append("|qa")
                .append("|r[eouw]")
                .append("|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]")
                .append("|(?:tel|travel|t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz])")
                .append("|u[agkmsyz]")
                .append("|v[aceginu]")
                .append("|w[fs]")
                .append("|y[etu]")
                .append("|z[amw]))")
                .append("|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]") // or ip address
                .append("[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]")
                .append("|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]")
                .append("[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}")
                .append("|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])))")
                .append("(?:\\:\\d{1,5})?)") // plus option port number
                .append("(\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\;\\/\\?\\:\\@\\&\\=\\#\\~")  // plus option query params
                .append("\\-\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\_])|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))*)?")
                .append("(?:\\b|$)").toString()
        );
    }
    return patternLink;
}
```

Comment: No idea how that matches. [Your regex does not match these strings](https://regex101.com/r/2Q0DjI/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i guess this is not for java. thanks for your goodwill

Comment: What do you mean not for Java? The pattern works the same in PCRE and Java for the string  I put in the test. Here is a [Java regex demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydx3p1nr)

Comment: Yeah, that worked. There was another problem. Thank you. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I would like to point out that your efforts at using `StringBuilder` will actually result in slower code than if you had just concatenated using `+`.  If you concatenate using `+` that will be a compile-time constant expression ... and all of the concatenations will be optimized away at compile time.  With your `StringBuilder` version, that can't happen.

Comment: @StephenC great suggestion.  thanks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Will you try that?  It worked for me.

```
public static final Pattern WEB_URL = Pattern.compile(
        "((?:(http|https|Http|Https|rtsp|Rtsp):\\/\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)"
        + "\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?:\\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_"
        + "\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\\@)?)?"
        + "(?:" + DOMAIN_NAME + ")"
        + "(?:\\:\\d{1,5})?)" // plus option port number
        + "(\\/(?:(?:[" + GOOD_IRI_CHAR + "\\;\\/\\?\\:\\@\\&\\=\\#\\~"  // plus option query params
        + "\\-\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\_])|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))*)?"
        + "(?:\\b|$)");
```